# Сохранение изменения нажатых ячеек (DBGrid/Lazarus/Delphi)

Tags: delphi, lazarus, dbgrid

В DBGrid выводим данные (из MSSQL-сервера, из представления), обработчик OnCellClick написан, делает то, что от него требуется.
Проблема в следующем: необходимо ячейки, которые были "кликнуты" закрасить/удалить значения/сделать цвет шрифта=цвету фона - без разницы.
Дошёл до примерно такого:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if gdSelected in State then
  begin
    with DBGrid1.Canvas do
    begin
      Brush.Color:=clWhite;
      Font.Color:=clWhite;
      FillRect(Rect);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Однако, закрашивается только та ячейка, которую выделили, после выделения другой ячейки закраска пропадает. Каким образом можно сохранить закраску "прокликаных" ячеек?

Comment: завести список ячеек, и при клике добавлять ячейку в этот список. в приведенной процедуре изменять параметры не для selеcted состояния, я проверяя находится ли ячейка в списке/

Comment: а если выбрать ячейки с зажатой клавишей Ctrl или Shift и выделить другую ячейку, закраска пропадет?